# Shade Smooth Render Lines

Tags: normals, distort

I want to simply smooth out the circle faces on the object using the Shade Smooth render selection. However, all the faces are affected by the smooth render and I get a stretched lines look to the faces. I tried to select (in edit mode) the required faces I want smoothed out but with applying the Shade Smoother render (in object mode) the whole object is affected by the smooth render. Thanks in advance with any help to resolve this.[image: Before the Smooth render][image: Edit view - Vertex view][image: Shade Smooth Render applied][image: Shade Smooth applied - Edit Mode view]

Comment: How do I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can smooth only some faces.

**Manual way:**
In *Edit mode*, select your faces and go to *Mesh > Shading > Smooth faces*.
this will only affect selected faces.
[image]

**Automatic way:**
Go to *Object Data* tab, and check *Auto Smooth* option.
You can set how sharp edges wil be affected.
Your object needs to be set to *Smooth Shading* for this to work.
[image]

You can still manually mark edges you want as sharp.
Just select your edges and go to *Edge > Mark Sharp*.
[image]

Comment: I tried the automatic way but it didn't work. Even when adjusting the Smooth Angle, there was no effect on the object. However, the manual method you posted worked. Thanks for helping me out. Cheers.

Comment: @Steb Hello :). You need to shade smooth your whole object first, for the Auto-smooth option to work. Without that, all faces stay flat.

Comment: ah yes, I see now that you mentioned that in your initial instructions. I guess I was rushing to get it fixed and wasn't paying enough attention. Thanks again.